# Java: efficient Collection concept for a paired objects

Tags: java, performance, collections

I'm missing some kind of collection functionality for a specific problem.

I'd like to start with a few informations about the problem's background - maybe there's a more elegant way to solve it, which doesn't end in the specific problem I'm stuck with:

I'm modelling a volume mesh made of tetrahedral cells (the 2D-analog would be a triangle mesh). Two tetrahedrons are considered to be adjacent if they share one triangle-face (which occupies three vertices). My application has to be able to navigate from cell to cell via their common face.

To meet some other requirements I had to split the faces into two so-called half-faces which share the same vertices but are belonging to different cells and have opposite orientation.

The application needs to be able to do calls like this (where `Face` models a half-face):

```
Cell getAdjacentCell(Cell cell, int faceIndex) {
    Face face = cell.getFace(faceIndex);
    Face partnerFace = face.getPartner();
    if (partnerFace == null) return null; // no adjacent cell present
    Cell adjacentCell = partnerFace.getCell();
    return adjacentCell;
}
```

The implementation of the `getPartner()`-method is the method in question. My approach is as follows:

`Face`-objects can create some kind of a immutable `Signature`-object containing merely the vertex-configuration, the orientation (clockwise (cw) or counter-clockwise (ccw)) and a back-reference to the originating Face-object. Face.Signature-objects are considered to be equal (`@Override equals()`) if they occupy the same three vertices - regardless of their orientation and their associated cell.

I created two sets in the `Mesh`-objects to contain all half-faces grouped by their orientation:

```
Set<Face.Signature> faceSignatureCcw = new HashSet<Face.Signature>();
Set<Face.Signature> faceSignatureCw = new HashSet<Face.Signature>();
```

Now I'm able to determine if a partner exists ...

```
class Face {
    public Face getPartner() {
        if (this.getSignature().isCcw()) {
            boolean partnerExists = this.getMesh().faceSignatureCw.contains(this);
        } else {
            boolean partnerExists = this.getMesh().faceSignatureCcw.contains(this);
        }
    }
}
```

... but `Set` does not allow to retrieve the specific object it contains! It merely confirms that it contains an object that matches via `.equals()`.

**(end of background informations)**

I need a `Collection`-concept which provides the following functionality:

- add a `Face`-Object to the Collection (duplicates are prohibited by the application and thus cannot occur)
- retrieve the partner from the Collection for a given `Face`-Object that `.equals()` but has the opposite orientation

A possible (but way to slow) solution would be:

```
class PartnerCollection {
    List<Face.Signature> faceSignatureCcw = new ArrayList<Face.Signature>();
    List<Face.Signature> faceSignatureCw = new ArrayList<Face.Signature>();

    void add(Face.Signature faceSignature) {
        (faceSignature.isCcw() ? faceSignatureCw : faceSignatureCcw).add(faceSignature);
    }

    Face.Signature getPartner(Face.Signature faceSignature) {
        List<Face.Signature> partnerList = faceSignature.isCcw() ? faceSignatureCw : faceSignatureCcw;
        for (Face.Signature partnerSignature : partnerList) {
            if (faceSignature.equals(partnerSignature)) return partnerSignature;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

To be complete: The final application will have to handle hundreds of thousands of `Face`-Objects in a real-time environment. So performance *is* an issue.

Thanks in advance to anyone who at least tried to follow me up to this point :)
I hope there's anyone out there having the right idea to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything wrong with using two `Map<Face.Signature, Face.Signature>`?
One for each direction?

That's what I'd do. There's practically no code to it.

Comment: Since the key portion of a `Map` is a `Set`, wouldn't I end up with the same problem as with my `Set`-Solution? I would be able to recognize that a partner object exists, but I would be unable to fetch the object itself. Or did I miss something?

Comment: ... in fact I did miss something - you're right. I should be able to retrieve the desired object using the entry's value. It's still some kind of memory wasting, but it should solve the original problem. I'll give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the design you have now, there is no way around something needing to iterate *somewhere*.  The question is, where you want that iteration to occur?  I suggest you do this:

```
    List<Face.Signature> partnerList = faceSignature.isCcw() ? faceSignatureCw : faceSignatureCcw;
    int idx = partnerList.indexOf(faceSignature);
    if(idx == -1)
       return null;
    return partnerList.get(idx);
```

Also, as long as you are using `Lists`, and know that the initial size will have to be pretty big, you might as well say, `new ArrayList(100000)` or so.

Of course, this isn't the only method, just one that ensures the iteration will be optimal.

EDIT:  After some thought, I believe the ideal data-structure for this would be an Octuply Linked List, which can make things confusing, but also very fast (comparatively).

Answer (score 0):

It's late night here and I haven't ready your question completely. So, I apologize if this doesn't make any sense, but do have you considered using a graph data structure?  If the graph data structure is indeed a possible solution, you might want to check out [jGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just giving each Face a partner data member?  As in,

```
public class Face
{
    Face partner;
    //whatever else
}
```

The `Face.Signature` construct is a bit hairy and really shouldn't be needed.  If every face has a partner (or enough `Face` objects can have a partner that it makes sense to think that there is a *has-a* relationship between a `Face` and a partner `Face`), the connection should just be an instance variable.  If you can use this approach, it should vastly simplify your code.  If not, post back the reason this doesn't work for you so that I can keep trying to help.

Comment: It's simply a design decision. The Signature allows me to define a different type of equality than I would use for the `Face`-class itself. I might fall back to a single instance-variable, if the solution doesn't require overriding `equals()` or `hashCode()`. However, there are some other application specific reasons suggesting the `Signature`-class you couldn't be aware of, as I didn't mention them. However, switching to an instance variable doesn't solve the problem itself.